# How to use an error handling function on another function?

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a script, `main.py`, that runs a few functions from other scripts in the directory. I had the very unoriginal idea to send myself Slack notifications if specific functions ran correctly or failed, i.e. error handling. **How would I use an error handling function located in a separate script - call the file `slack_notifications.py` - in my `main.py` script?** [This linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64859427/handling-errors-using-a-extra-function) question starts to get at the answer, but it doesn't get to the calling the error function from somewhere else.

`main.py` script:

```
import scraper_file
import slack_notifications

# picture scrape variable
scrape_object = 'Barack Obama'

# scraper function called 
scraped_image = scraper_file.pic_scrape(scrape_object)

# error handling?
slack_notifications.scrape_status(scrape_object)
```

I have tried embedding the called scraper function into the `scrape_status()` function, like this: `scraped_image = (slack_notifications.scrape_status(scraper_file.pic_scrape(scrape_object)))` and a few other ways, but that doesn't really tell you if it ran successfully, right?

`slack_notifications.py` script:

```
testing = "dunderhead"

def scrape_status(x):

    # if this function gets a positive return from the scrape function
    # if this function gets any error from the scrape function
    try:
        x
        print(x + ' worked!')
    except:
        print(x + ' failed!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape_status(testing)
```

Is there a way to do this? I have been going off [these instructions](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/), too.

Comment: your `scrape_status` seems totally useless. It will run `try/except` too late - after error hapends - so it can't catch it. You would have to rather send function's name (without `()` ) into `scrape_status` and use it with `()` to execute it inside `try/except` - and then it can catch it. OR simply you have to run `scraper_file.pic_scrape(scrape_object)` inside `try/except` and it would be simpler if you use `try/except` directly inside `scraper_file.pic_scrape(scrape_object)` instead of  creating universal function `scrape_Status()` for `this`

Comment: code in yoiur first works because function `input()` was moved from outside `error_handler` into inside `error_handler` and you would have to do the same with `scraper_file.pic_scrape(scrape_object)` - you have to move it into `scrape_status` but you can't do this using `scraper_file.pic_scrape(scrape_object)` because it runs it outside `scrape_status`. All your idea is overcomplicated. Better put all code in one file and don't try to create universal function `scrape_status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in your first link works because function `input()` was moved from outside `error_handler()` into inside `error_handler()` and it is executed inside `try/except.

Your code always runs function outside error handler `scrape_status()` and it sends only result from executed function - so it never runs it inside `try/except`.

You would have to send separatelly function's name (without `()` and arguments) and separatelly arguments - and then it can run it inside `try/except`

```
def scrape_status(function, *args):
    try:
        function(*args)
        print(function.__name__ + ' worked!')
    except:
        print(function.__name__ + ' failed!')
```

But it means you have to send function as

```
scrape_status(scraper_file.pic_scrape, scrape_object)
```

instead of

```
scrape_status( scraper_file.pic_scrape(scrape_object) )
```

and this is not readable - so I don't know if it is good idea to create universal error handler.

---

Minimal working example

```
def scrape_status(function, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)  # some functions may return result
        print(function.__name__ + ' worked!')
        return result
    except:
        print(function.__name__ + ' failed!')

# ----

# this function needs `arg1, arg2` to work correctly
def testing(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)

# --- main ---
    
print('--- test 1 ---')    
# send funciton's name `testing` and argument(s) `'hello', 'world'`   
scrape_status(testing, 'hello', 'world')  # OK

print('--- test 2 ---')    
# send funciton's name `testing` without argument(s) 
scrape_status(testing)  # ERROR
```

Result:

```
--- test 1 ---
hello world
testing worked!
--- test 2 ---
testing failed!
```

---

**EDIT:**

I created new example using decorator based on answers in question [General decorator to wrap try except in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572288/general-decorator-to-wrap-try-except-in-python). Now code use readableand it needs to use decorator `@scrape_status('')` only when function is defined

```
@scrape_status('')
def testing(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)
```

Minimal working code:

```
def scrape_status():
  def decorate(function):
    def applicator(*args, **kwargs):
      try:
         result = function(*args, **kwargs)
         print(function.__name__ + ' worked!')
         return result
      except:
         print(function.__name__ + ' failed!')

    return applicator

  return decorate

# ----

# this function needs `arg1, arg2` to work correctly
@scrape_status()
def testing(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)

# --- main ---
  
print('--- test 1 ---')    
# send function's name `testing` and argument(s) `'hello', 'world'`   
testing('hello', 'world')  # OK

print('--- test 2 ---')    
# send function's name `testing` without argument(s) 
testing()  # ERROR
```

---

As I remeber there could be some module(s) with more complex decorators - ie. one decorator could repeate function 3 times if it was raising error. It could be uses to repeate question in `input()` if answer was wrong, or repeate downloading file if there was problem to download it.

Comment: Gotcha - I agree, does look totally useless. Will try this out after work!

Comment: maybe it could be more readable with some decorator like in answers for [General decorator to wrap try except in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572288/general-decorator-to-wrap-try-except-in-python). Or maybe there is module for this

Comment: I created code using decorator from question ` General decorator to wrap try except in python?.` and now code is nice and readable.